# Как правильно расставить пунктуацию?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение: "Мне задали вопросы про ряды Тейлора и теоремы Эйлера и Кёнига." Мне кажется, что запятые здесь не нужны. Но, так как "и" несколько, то, возможно, их нужно поставить.

Comment: Гмм, в каком контексте возникают такие вопросы про анализ и комбинаторику? Или это мнимая ситуация?

Comment: Мне кажется, выйдет более гладко, если повторить предлог — *"...и про теоремы Эйлера и Кёнига"*. В остальном согласен с ответом J-mster'а, запятых тут не нужно.

Comment: @KCd на собеседовании, наверное, могли спросить про все подряд. Но в любом случае, _теоремы Эйлера_ в этой фразе звучат двусмысленно, их же в каждой области математики по несколько :)

Comment: Я для примера написал:) хотя в курсе дискретной математики все 3 использовались

Comment: @yanpas, Вы имеете в виду формальные степенные ряды, не ряды Тейлора? Обычно, когда степенные ряды возникают в дискретной математике, точка зрения рядов Тейлора (круг сходимости или другие аналитические свойства) не используются.

Comment: @KCd Почти) В производящей функции ФСР последовательность совпадала с рядом тейлора. Только там не было o(n) в конце, но я не помню нужна ли она вообще

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы правы, никаких запятых не нужно.
Здесь два ряда однородных членов предложения:

1. *вопросы про (что?) ряды и теоремы*
2. *теоремы (чьи?) Эйлера и Кёнига*

В каждом ряду - свой союз *и*.